# ice:effect, change the startcolor of effectType="highlight"

Tags: jsf, icefaces

How I can change the color of effectType="highlight" in the

```
<ice:effect effectType="highlight"/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
<ice:effect event="mouseover" effectType="highlight" options="startcolor:'#66CCFF',duration:1.0" >
```